# Swift MVC: Having viewController observe Model property, updating the view when the property changes

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, key-value-observing

The main class of my model is Concentration with a property called flipCount

```
class Concentration {
    @objc var flipCount = 0
```

In My ViewController I have an @IBOutlet to a UILabel called flipCountLabel

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    lazy var game = Concentration(numberOfPairsOfCards: self.cardButtons.count / 2)
    @IBOutlet weak var flipCountLabel: UILabel!
...
```

I want to update the text in flipCountLabel when flipCount changes. I am trying to do this by placing a call to the observe method of UIViewController in my ViewController's viewDidLoad method. There are a few observe methods. I don't know which one is right and cannot find an example for how to what to fill in the variables with.

I have tried to use self.observe like

```
    self.observe(KeyPath<Concentration,Int>(game, "flipCount"), changeHandler: {
        self.flipCountLabel.text = "Flip Count: \(flipCount)"
    })
```

---

I am trying to update the ViewControllers flipCountLabel.text every time game.flipCount is updated.
I think this is kvo?

Comment: @Don I can't access flipCountLabel within the Concentration class. The IBOutlet is in the ViewController

Comment: Oh, sorry. Didn't read closely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `observe` method is the way to go here, be it with some changes to your code.

Change your `Concentration` class to the following:

```
class Concentration: NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var flipCount = 0
}
```

In order for KVO to work in Swift, properties need to be marked with both `@objc` and `dynamic`. The class needs to inherit from `NSObject` to prevent runtime errors.

Your `ViewController` class should look something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @objc lazy var game = Concentration()
    @IBOutlet weak var flipCountLabel: UILabel!

    private var observation: NSKeyValueObservation?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.observation = self.observe(\.game.flipCount) { _, _ in
            self.flipCountLabel.text = "\(self.game.flipCount)"
        }
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        self.observation = nil
    }
}
```

The `game` property needs to be marked `@objc` (again to prevent runtime errors). Furthermore, the [documentation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/swift-4.0-RELEASE/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/NSObject.swift#L184) of the `observe` method states

> when the returned NSKeyValueObservation is deinited or invalidated, it
>   will stop observing

This is why you need to keep a strong reference to the value returned by the `observe` method.

Also, consider using the KeyPath notation I used here. If you make a typo, it will fail when compiling, instead of at runtime.

I hope this helps you out!

Comment: When I place @Objc in front of lazy var game = Concentration, I receive `Property cannot be marked @objc because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C`

Comment: That's why you need to make `Concentration` a subclass of `NSObject`